# determine whether a point of a set is in the interior point

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

Let $A \subseteq \Bbb R^2$ with $A = \{(x,y): 1<x<4, 1<y<3 \}$.
Is the point $(2,2)$ be an interior point of $A$?
Is the point $(4,2)$ be an interior point of $A$?
Justify!

**Attempt:** **Edit:**
I know that the answer is yes and no, respectively.
But, I'm not sure how to show it.

To show: $(2,2)$ is an interior point of $A$.
Let $w \in B(u,r)$ with $u=(2,2)$. Let $r=\frac{1}{2}>0$ and $k=\frac{1}{2} - ||w-u||$. Then,
$k > 0$ since $||w-u|| < \frac{1}{2}$. Let $x \in B(w,k)$. Then, by the triangle inequality,
\begin{equation*}
||x-u|| \le ||x-w|| + ||w-u|| \le k + ||w-u|| = \frac{1}{2}.
\end{equation*}
Thus, $x \in B(u,\frac{1}{2})$ so that $B(w,k) \subseteq B(u,\frac{1}{2}) \subseteq A$.
Hence, $w$ is an interior point of $A$ such that $B(u,\frac{1}{2}) \subseteq int(A)$ and so, $u$ is an interior point of $A$.

How to show it?

On the other hand, a point $x \in A$ is an interior point of $A$ if there exists $r>0$ such that $B(x,r) \subseteq A$ i.e.
there exists $r>0$ such that for all $y \in \Bbb R^2, ||y-x||<r \implies y \in A$.

Comment: What you wrote about $(2,2)$ is right. for $(4,2)$ show that every small ball that is centered there must contain points with x - coordinate that is not belong to A, hence the point is not part of A

Answer (score 3):

$A = (1,4) \times (1,3)$ is open in $\Bbb R^2$ so all of its points are interior points.